# lvm2 is not configured and masked, failed to unmask

Tags: lvm, ubuntu-18.04

I am installing `libguestfs0` and there is a dependencies called `lvm2` is required to be configured.

When i run `systemctl status lvm2`, it showing the service is masked (/dev/null, bad). Hence i try with `systemctl unmask lvm2` and `systemctl restart lvm2`. However it still failed to be started.

Please assist if you have any idea, thanks!

I am running in VM with Ubuntu 18 loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's normal for the `lvm2` service to be masked: it has been replaced by a  number of more granular services:

```
$ systemctl list-units lvm2*
UNIT                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
lvm2-lvmetad.service loaded active running   LVM2 metadata daemon
lvm2-monitor.service loaded active exited    Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling
lvm2-lvmetad.socket  loaded active running   LVM2 metadata daemon socket
lvm2-lvmpolld.socket loaded active listening LVM2 poll daemon socket
```